# What's the second Fréchet derivative of the tensor product of two Fréchet differentiable functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, frechet-derivative

Let

- $X,Y,E$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach spaces
- $f:E\to X$ and $g:E\to Y$ be twice Fréchet differentiable

> What's the second Fréchet derivative of $f\otimes g$?

$f\otimes g$ has to be understood as the mapping $$X\to E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:F\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto f(x)\otimes g(x)\tag1.$$

My own calculations yielded $${\rm D}(f\otimes g)={\rm D}f\otimes g+f\otimes{\rm D}g\tag2$$ and $${\rm D}^2(f\otimes g)={\rm D}^2f\otimes g+2{\rm D}f\otimes{\rm D}g+f\otimes{\rm D}^2g\tag3.$$ However, with $(2)$ we obtain for the simple example $E=X=Y$ and $f=g=\operatorname{id}_X$ $$({\rm D}^2(f\otimes g)(x)y)z=2y\otimes y\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y,z\in E\tag4$$ which seems to be wrong.

Comment: Why do you assume your answer is wrong?

Comment: @MichaelLee I assume it is wrong, because of the example $(4)$: If you choose $E=\mathbb R$ in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756015/what-is-the-second-fr%c3%a9chet-derivative-of-x-mapsto-x-otimes-x), then ${\rm D}^2f(X)=1$ and hence it's obvious that the desired claim $(1)$ (numbering of the other question) holds. And since I expect that the claim is true for any Banach space, I think that there must be something wrong with my calculation of the derivative.

Comment: What you wrote in (2), while very attractive, necessitates to be interpreted correctly. Remark Df and Dg are functions with values linear functions and not vectors. Then, all should follow smoothly using Leibniz rule (calculations).